# Button causing entries in the table to be repeated again and again

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have written a code for making entries in jTable.When a button is pressed entries are made in the table.Now the problem which is occurring is that every time when a button is pressed the entries which were previously present ,they are also present there and these same entries are made again and this process continues as long as we keep pressing the code.How to stop this?

```
private void EvaluationMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      

    Panel.setVisible(true);
    Function f1=new Function();
    f1.evaluate();

    HashMap<String, msg> b = f1.evaluate();
    int i = 0;

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) Table.getModel();

    for (i = 1; i <= b.size(); i++) {

        String skey = Integer.toString(i);
        model.addRow(new Object[] {
            b.get(skey).From,b.get(skey).To,b.get(skey).msg
        });
    }    
}
```

Comment: Of course you are going to get a new row every time - it's right in your handler where you call addRow. What is the desired functionality? Do you just want it to happen once?

Comment: I am exactly sure what you mean, but if you want to remove old entries before adding new ones try "table.removeAll()".

Comment: @Marc I used this function but still the result is same but now i am keeping a check by if condition.So,now the code is working correctly...  :)

Comment: @user1291492 I want the results to be displayed every time when a button is pressed but it should display the same results everytime.it should not make the same results to appear in table multiple times